# Some assets not displaying on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, asset-pipeline

I've added some new images to my app and they display fine locally, but not in production on Heroku. The CSS reference that is generated is correct:

```
background-image: url("glyphicons-halflings-white.png")
```

That ultimately links to http://www.photoramblr.com/assets/glyphicons-halflings-white.png

There's no image there, but other images I've uploaded in the past are sitting there under /assets/... For instance [this one](http://www.photoramblr.com/assets/icon_thumbs_up-85aad0d2bc5cde2a13fee99b1efa0832.png). Interestingly, if I take the long string of numbers out, leaving just the original filename, the image is blank...

Asset precompiling seemed to work fine when deploying, and I've just tried running asset:precompile manually on the server, but still no image.

Any thoughts?

UPDATE: BTW, here's a look at my `config/application.rb`:

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  # Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module PhotoRambler
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
    config.assets.compress = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather weirdly, upgrading from Rails 3.1 to Rails 3.2.6 has fixed my issue. No idea why.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the new assets are checked into the source control.

Comment: They are. Since asking this question I've also tried out this https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails which is a gem that provides icons and they are stored in his own repo; again works fine in development, but I get nothing in production. Doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using less/bootstrap, and my images in CSS are encoded like this:

```
background: image-url("delete.gif") no-repeat ;
```